# WiX Duplicate Version Product Installed

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I created a MSI "appA.msi" with WiX 3.5 and have discrete GUIDs in the .wxs file for

```
Product Id
UpdgradeCode
Package Id
```

I do not have any component GUIDs specified.

It installs like this:

```
...program files...
.....homedir
.......launcher.exe
.........appdirA
...........app.exe
...........app.exe.config
```

I then built another MSI with the same project called "appB.msi", all bits the saedited the app.exe.config file, changed the GUIDs for

```
Product Id
UpdgradeCode
Package Id
```

And I expected it to install like this:

```
...program files...
.....homedir
.......launcher.exe
.........appdirB
...........app.exe
...........app.exe.config
```

(yes launcher.exe is the same file going in the same spot)

But instead of installing, I get the message "Another version of this product is already installed."

But AFAIK the versions are completely different, right?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your project contain a `<Upgrade>` tag?

Comment: Check the GUID of your upgrade tag. It will be same in both the setups.

Comment: I guess both appB.msi and appA.msi have the same PackageId or ProductId. The GUIDs of component with launcher.exe should be the same in both packages, yet app.exe and app.exe.config must be different.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you are best off using the ?????-??? format for the package code and for the product code rather than using a static one that you have to keep editing.

Not setting the component GUIDs means the components will be orphaned on the system.

Do you need these two packages to co-exist or should they be mututally exclusive. Depending on the answer you may need to put a little more work into them.